# Name of Famous Triangle Area Formula? $A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(C)$

Tags: geometry, area

I'm sorry for this short question, but I really could not find the answer to this anywhere.

Is there a name for the formula $A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(C)$?

Comment: This particular method has been used in some form since the year $500$ A.D. in India by Indian mathematician [Aryabhata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata).  In practice though, I often simply hear it referred to as the "one-half base times height" formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard it called the SAS (side-angle-side) area formula.

Comment: Yup, a google search tells me that seems to be right. I'll accept when the time limit goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just called the sine formula for the area of a triangle. In any case, it is easily derivable. Given a triangle $ABC$

[image]

we can say that the area of the rectangle is $hb$ and thus that the area of the triangle is $\dfrac{1}{2}hb$. But we can also say that $h = a\sin{C}$ giving rise to the formula $A = \dfrac{1}{2}ab \sin{C}$.